# sub-levels {description} latex

Tags: lists, description

I work latex with the `description` list but its sub-levels are limited. The most we can get is up to seven levels.

After searching the latex documentation, we find the `easylist` environment, but the spacing and alignment needs to be done manually.

Is there any other similar environment to `description` or some way to increase your number of sub-levels?

Comment: You could use the package enumitem. But imho lists with more than 4 levels are a nuisance.